# Refresh the only object in ObjectListView

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I use [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html). And use method RefreshObject() to update the only modified object.

```
// The difference between associations and updatedAssociations is only in 
// one item, which ID field remains the same. 
// So i find an updated item by ID in the associations (before updating). 
//And say Object ListView to to refresh this item. 

var associationToUpdate = associations.References.Where(
        x => x.ID == associationIDToUpdate).FirstOrDefault();

olvAssociations.RefreshObject(associationToUpdate);

// And only after this set the model to updated model

associations = updatedAssociations;
```

But nothing happens. Does anybody know that's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

olv gives me fits, too. do i understand that you update your model outside the objectlistview edit provisional? the function you refresh meant to force updates to the model from edits made in the objectlistview itself.

if you are updating the model outside the view, objectlistview says it updates the display automatically. that statement is a truth not relative to me, but i am still researching. i'll update here if i find a nice resolution.

[objectlistview, interesting feature - search for "After the update"](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/cellEditing.html)

edit:

i didn't find an answer that works for me yet, but these may work for you:

[objectlistview, 2 force-redraw functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525828/how-do-i-add-remove-items-to-a-listview-in-virtual-mode)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for:

```
objectListView.RefreshItem(item);
```

Comment: RefreshItem() can be used to manually update an OLVListItem. But OP is trying to updating the model.