# How to show icon on all listview items in virtual mode (C#)

Tags: c#, image, listview, virtualmode

I'm using virtual mode of listview to show a larg data. But I don't know how to show image for each item. Who can help me ?

I wrote

```
private void ListContact_RetrieveVirtualItem(object sender, RetrieveVirtualItemEventArgs e)
    {
        MyContact contact = ContactData.GetMyContact(e.ItemIndex);
        if (e.Item == null) e.Item = new ListViewItem(contact.ToString());
        if (contact.Photo != null)
        {
            e.Item.ImageList.Images.Add("" + contact.Id, contact.Photo);
            e.Item.ImageKey = "" + contact.Id;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Item.ImageKey = "default";
        }
    }
```

But it don't work properly

Comment: What is error message? And possible you should look this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525828/how-do-i-add-remove-items-to-a-listview-in-virtual-mode

Comment: No, no error. But when runtime, i don't see any image.

Comment: private void ListContact_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
        {
            e.DrawDefault = true;
        }

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in the .NET Framework (that's been marked as **Won't fix**). You might want to check [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/430731/listview-fails-to-display-image-set-by-key-when-in-virtual-mode) out. The solution would be to use `ImageIndex` instead of `ImageKey`.

Comment: Thanks you. I have just tested and result is successfull.

Comment: @VõQuangHòa: Glad I could help. If this solved your problem, please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I have just read this rule from faq. But I'm sorry, I can't see "accepted answer" any where. Please help me. Thanks you

Comment: Source link is now dead (good job Microsoft, sigh) so whatever background information it contained is lost but the answer of using `ImageIndex` over `ImageKey` is still valid 6 years on having just been bitten by the exact same issue.

Comment: @RichardMoss Just like the classic **_This thread has been closed as of 26/Oct/2009_**