# BrightIdeasSoftware treeListView1 remove selectedobject

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to remove a selected root node with children but can figure it out.
Sometimes I get "the ListView is in virtual mode, you cannot remove items from the ListView items collection."

Im trying to add DoublClick on item and have that item be removed from the list.

```
    private void treeListView1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        treeListView1.Items.RemoveAt(treeListView1.SelectedIndex);
        treeListView1.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the code which is removing the node?

Comment: This may help: [How do I add/remove items to a ListView in virtual mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2527588/3110834)

Comment: there is no code as anything I tried it did not work.  For something so mundane I thought there would be more examples.